# AWS ec2 instance(Bare Metal) Provisioning with Puppet 4.5.1(OpenSource) not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, puppet, erb, aws-sdk

I am trying to provision aws ec2 instance with my puppet master. I want to utilize `user_data` field provided by aws-sdk and install puppet-agent on the node. For now I am only able to create an instance with the help of puppet.

```
ec2_instance { 'p-node':
  ensure        => running,
  region        => 'ap-southeast-1',
  image_id      => 'ami-25c00c46',
  key_name      => 'POC-KeyPair',
  instance_type => 't2.micro',
  security_groups => 'launch-wizard-1',
  subnet        => 'dashboard-pub-subnet-1',
  user_data     => template('agent-pe-userdata.erb'),
}
```

**agent-pe-userdata.erb**

```
#!/bin/bash

PE_MASTER='<%= @pe_master_hostname %>'

PE_CERTNAME=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)

curl -sk https://$PE_MASTER:8140/packages/current/install.bash | /bin/bash -s agent:certname=$PE_CERTNAME
```

In my case puppet is not able to find the `templatedir` option provided by puppet.

```
#puppet apply site.pp --test --templatedir templates
Error: Could not parse application options: invalid option: --templatedir
```

Kindly suggest whats I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `--templatedir` is literally not a `puppet apply` argument (https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/man/apply.html), so what is it you are trying to do with it? The default template directory is `templates` in the corresponding module directory, which is what it looks like you are attempting to specify manually.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I am trying to use sample agent-pe-userdata.erb given by aws to setup puppet-agent on the newly created node. Got the reference from here:(https://puppet.com/blog/using-puppet-to-launch-a-puppet-enterprise-cluster-aws)

Comment: If this is not possible, please suggest any other way to achieve this. I want to create an ec2 instance and bootstrap puppet-agent to it.

Comment: That blog article is for an obsolete version of puppet. You should use the latest documentation for the module at its github page: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-aws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed "agent-pe-userdata.erb" file in the wrong path. It should be inside puppet/templates folder.